# Python library for hydrology calculations for multiple points

Tags: python, dem, hydrology, flow-accumulation

I have a DEM (TIFF) with multiple points, which mark wells (right term?) of an underground pipe network:
[image: image section of DEM with points]

I was wondering if there is a Python library which uses the elevation of the DEM to generate a catchment areas (like a polygon) along all of the points. Based on these calculated catchment areas I would like to create water flow networks showing potential flow streams for each point based on the DEM.

I found [pysheds](https://github.com/mdbartos/pysheds), which is calculating catchment areas as well as flow networks but just for one single outlet/pour point. So I was wondering if there is something out there considering more than just a single point?

Or should I use pysheds, re-run it for all single points (e.g. with a loop through an array of points) and afterwards combine the single catchment areas as well as the single flow networks in one file each?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/mdbartos/pysheds/issues/64#issuecomment-462951248). It's from a pysheds issue. He creates a `for loop`. Note, it looks like some of the code from the example is outdated. So you'll need to fix it.